# Trying to write a code in Python 3 that asks for how many steps to draw the stairs

Tags: python, string, loops, while-loop

I am trying to write a program/code that asks the user for how many steps to draw the stairs. The user will always enter an integer greater than zero. Example, if entered 4, the output should be next:

```
 How many steps? 4
_ _   #top line made out of 2 underscores
   |_
     |_
       |_
______ _ |  #bottom line consist of 8 underscores
```

The horizontal lines are created using underscores (_) and the vertical lines using the pipe character (|).

My code is next:

```
    n = int(input("How many steps? "))
    print('_ _') 
    while n > 0:
        n = n-1
        a = "  |_"
        print (n*a)
        print (n*'|_')
        print('_'*2*n, '|')
```

This is what I get:

```
   How many steps? 4
    _ _
      |_  |_  |_
    |_|_|_
    ______ |
      |_  |_
    |_|_
    ____ |
      |_
    |_
    __ |
    __ |

     |
```

I am confused with those lines. Thanks for help!

Comment: What's the current behavior of the program?

Comment: You may want to specify if this is [tag:python-2.7] or [tag:python-3.x].

Comment: This is going to be get closed as off topic, can you provide a specific problem you are having with your current code?  Also, `print = ` is invalid python taking into consideration your next line.

Comment: @chrisz It's valid Python 3, it reassigns the value of `print` (let me check)

Comment: @chrisz [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Pz8npaAoM69EwVYBTHPBeIZcMCkNMKn5/z8A)

Comment: It's valid python, but the following line is not because of the assignment.

Comment: Python 3. 
I removed print = ......I am not getting this step....the lines just go below each other

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution for this exercise. Thanks everybody for all your comments, help and time!

```
steps = int(input("How many steps? "))
print ('__')
i = 1
while i <steps:
    print((' ' * (i*2)) + '|_')
    i = i+1
print ('_'*(i*2) + '|')
```